# Promise rejects with await are not catches by the Middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, error-handling

I'm using Nodejs.

I have a promise which request after a few seconds.
But my Middleware not catches the error, but uncaughtException does.

```
router.all('/incaseoferror', async(req, res, next) => {

    const promise = await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            reject(new Error('this is a test err, the error-middleware NOT catch and it NOT OKAY'));
        }, 3000);
    });

  //  throw new Error('test error - the error-middleware catch it and that okay');
});

function clientErrorHandler(err, req, res, next) {

    console.log('in clientErrorHandler', err);
//but not catch the promise error!

});

process.on('uncaughtException', function (error) {

    // the error is catch here..
});
```

**Here is the problem:**
Let's say I have login function from another library and it give me a promise.
something has failed in the function, I cant catch the error in my error-middleware to give the user response that the request is failed.

1. I dont want to add try/catch in every middleware. (route===middleware)
2. I want use async/await
3. Using uncaughtException not help me because I can't return response to the user in the route.

So what can I do? any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it's time to switch from Express to Koa...

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

```
await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            reject(new Error('this is a test err, the error-middleware NOT catch and it NOT OKAY'));
        }, 3000);
    })
.catch((err) => {
    clientErrorHandler(err);
 });
```

Comment: No. I Also want to use async/await. NOT Then/catch.

Comment: I am using async/await to get the promise; You mean even for catching error you want to use async/await?

Comment: No, I just expect to same behavior when I does `throw new Error` and the middleware catch. so for promise reject.

Comment: So, even the first half of my answer doesnt satisfy your requirement. Am i right?

Comment: @ShlomiLevi  I have updated the answer.